# How to access a values of variable created by value of another variable

Tags: variables, groovy

Can someone help me to find a way to read a value from a variable which made using another variable in groovy?

```
environment = "DEV1"
DEV1_Server = "serverabc" 
DeploymentServer = "${${environment}_Server}"
println "${DeploymentServer}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
environment = "DEV1"
DEV1_Server = "serverabc" 
println this."${environment}_Server"
```